# SQL Group by multiple non-unique occurrences

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (name TEXT, num INTEGER, hash TEXT)
```

I need to get a row returned for each unique hash for which the following conditions are true:

1. The hash occurs more than once
2. More than one value of "num" is associated with the hash

As an example, suppose I have this table:

```
name | num  | hash
-----+------+-------
  A  |  1   | 123
  B  |  1   | 123
  C  |  2   | 456
  D  |  3   | 456
  E  |  4   | 789
  F  |  4   | 789
  G  |  5   | 789
```

I want the following returned:

```
hash
----
 456
 789
```

I don't want "123" because this hash occurs uniquely with num=1.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(hash) > 1 AND COUNT(num) > 1;
```

But this doesn't work, because it's not separating the `hash` column from the `num` column. I tried several variations such as group by both columns, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT hash
FROM tab
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT num) > 1;
```

However, I would be inclined to write:

```
SELECT hash
FROM tab
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
       MIN(num) <> MAX(num);
```

Note:  Don't use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st condition:

> The hash occurs more than once

is not needed as it is fully covered by the 2nd:

> More than one value of "num" is associated with the hash

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select distinct t.hash
from tab t
where exists (
  select 1 from tab 
  where hash = t.hash and num <> t.num
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1mEZpXHy5RYVhimrN3WL6/0)